# Snap to nearest street

Tags: google-maps, driving-directions

You guys have been helping out solving some of my problems with a Google Map lately, and thank you for that.

I am almost done with this - only one problem is left. When I place the first marker on the map, it snaps to the nearest street (which is fine!) but when I drag the first marker to another place, directions suddenly mess up. And the markers get mixes.

You can see an example on http://dev.korebogen.dk/gmap/

I need to make it possible to move the first marker (still snapping) and when I place the second marker, the directions first load. But in order to make the first marker snap again, I have to load the directions.

I hope some of you have a solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Blackpool Community Church Javascript Team has an [excellent example of exactly this](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/snap.htm) ([direct link to the fourth example](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example_snappathdrag.htm)). Check out their other examples as well.

(disclaimer: I'm not affiliated with them, but have learned a lot about GMaps from their examples)

Edit:
I suspect the map events fire somewhat like this (pseudocode, for real event names etc. check the GMaps docs):

- map click: mousedown, mouseup, click:{set red marker}
- drag red marker: mousedown, dragstart{red marker}, mouseup, **click:{set marker b}** (mousedown+mouseup), dragend
- both markers are set? Yes, get directions

What I'd suggest: in red-marker and marker-A dragstart functions, set some flag "dragging a marker", reset it in dragend function; in the Set marker B function, only set marker if we're currently NOT dragging something (flag is not set).

Comment: I've checked them out and incorporated some of their code in my example, but it is not working as intended. No clue what I've done wrong.

Comment: I will try something new with the fourth example, 2 secs. :)

Comment: I can not get it to work as intended. Is it possible for you to cook up something that'll work with my code?

Comment: @Jan: checked your site in Opera 10, FF 3 and IE 7, works correctly the way you describe it - or I'm reading it wrong. Can you describe the steps that should happen and the steps that actually happen? Also, in what browser?

Comment: Thanks for your time. Sure; When the map is loaded I plot the first marker (red) - It automatic snaps to the nearest street -> Perfect!

Lets say I placed the marker wrong, and want to drag it to the right place: I drag the red marker, and suddenly it loads directions on the map - and add a A and a B marker - But I only wanted to move my red marker - not load directions yet. When the red marker is placed correctly - I place my second, and the directions load. This is what I'm seeking. Right now It just messes up if I drag the red (first) marker. Sorry for my broken english.

Answer (score 2):

The code I gave you previously listened for the first two clicks, and added a marker for each.  The problem is that when you drag the first marker, it's calling the "click" event again - and thus adding another marker at the same location.

Fortunately, the [click event](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GMap2.click) lets you know whether an overlay was clicked.  So only execute the code that adds a new marker if overlay is null. *Note that overlay is not a boolean.*

```
var listener = GEvent.addListener(map, "click", function(overlay, latlng) {
  if (overlay == null) {
    // code to add new marker
  }
});
```

Comment: I incorporated your previous code in my example (might need refresh). And it works - I can drag the first marker without messing up. But I need the first marker to snap to the nearest road (click and on drag), so i can avoid plotting the marker on a field for example. 

I'm apparently not very good at Google Maps API or Javascript for getting this to work. I appreciate your help.