# How to change default markers in google map api3 direction service?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder

I want to change the default marker icons A, B and waypoint icons (reference image attached below).

[image]

Also this markers can be draggable. If i drag those markers, it should placed on the road except sea, rivers etc. I tried so many ways in last week. I didn't find any solution last one week.

Comment: whats your current code for adding markers

Comment: [example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_directions-waypointsE.html)

Comment: @geocodezip, in your example the waypoint icon is not postioned properly if i drag the marker.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the marker with this :

```
directionsDisplay.setOptions( { suppressMarkers: true } );
```

As you have the direction param "destination" you know where you're going, so you're then totally fine to add another one by yourself :

```
var latlngDestination = new google.maps.LatLng(???,???) ;
var markerDestination = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: latlngDestination,
            draggable: true,
            icon: 'http://www.google.com/mapfiles/markerA.png'
    });

    directionsService.route({
        origin: ???,
        destination: latlngDestination ,
        travelMode: 'DRIVING'
    }
```

For the snapping part you have the same question and solution here : [Snap to nearest street](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805792/snap-to-nearest-street)